# how to do a sql inner join between 2 tables when using a partial key?

Tags: sql

Can anyone give me an example of a sql inner join between 2 tables when using a partial key?

For example:

```
======
Table1
======

StudentID: STUDENT00001, STUDENT00002, STUDENT00999


======
Table2
======

ID: 00001, 00002, 00999
```

My code so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.StudentID = ***how do i add a prefix here?*** Table2.ID
```

THANKS!

Comment: What is your database server (if it is not SQL Server)?

Comment: thanks for the answers guys how do i do this in MYSQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the CONCAT() function in MySQL.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.StudentID = CONCAT('STUDENT',Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 
  INNER JOIN Table2
    ON Table1.StudentID = CONCAT('STUDENT', RIGHT(100000 + Table2.ID, 5))
```

[`CONCAT(str1, str2, …)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) returns a string that is the result of concatenation of `str1`, `str2` etc.

[`RIGHT(str, len)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_right) returns `str`'s rightmost `len` characters. `str` in this case is represented by the result of `100000 + Table2.ID`, implicitly converted to a string.

I am assuming here that `Table2.ID` is an integer, so the entire `RIGHT()` expression is intended to turn the integer into a string where the integer value is padded with zeros. If `Table2.ID` is a string and is already padded with zeros, you don't need `RIGHT`, of course. The join condition would then look just like this:

```
… ON Table1.StudentID = CONCAT('STUDENT', Table2.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should simply be able to concat

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.StudentID = 'STUDENT'+CAST(t2.ID AS NVARCHAR)
```

Comment: Agree, but the `Table2.ID` is a `varchar` already, assuming it contains strings `00001` (if it was an int it would be `1`)

Comment: True though was just covering myself in-case it weren't the outcome would be the same :)

Comment: I would have used `'STUDENT' || CAST...` as `||` is the SQL concatenation operator. Or at least state which RDBMS uses `+` instead of `||`

Comment: Another point is that the `CAST` thought is good but it won't cover you in case `t2.ID` is integer. You need to "pad" zeros to the left.